# how to export checkbox value to csv file ?

Tags: javascript, html, css, forms, csv

here is the **html code** below.
Need to export the checked value to a csv file separated by comma 
Can any one help me out with any solutions. 
`

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="home.css">
        <title>CSB Export</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="page_wrapper">
            <div class="header">
                ABC news
            </div>
            <div class="form_holder">
                <form>
                    <div class="form_container">
                        Name : <input type="text" placeholder="Enter Your Name"/><br/>
                        <input type="checkbox" name="newstype" value="1"/>1<br/>
                        <input type="checkbox" name="newstype" value="2"/>2<br/>
                        <input type="checkbox" name="newstype" value="3"/>3<br/>
                        <input type="checkbox" name="newstype" value="4"/>4<br/>
                        <input type="checkbox" name="newstype" value="5"/>5<br/>

                        <input type="submit" value="submit"/>
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please add an example of your desired output.

Answer (score 0):

Use PHP:

```
if (isset($_POST['newstype1'])) {
//code for checked 1
} elseif  (isset($_POST['newstype2'])) {
//code for checked 2
} elseif  (isset($_POST['newstype3'])) {
//code for checked 3
} elseif  (isset($_POST['newstype4'])) {
//code for checked 4 
} else {
//code for checked 5
}
```

I hope that works. (and helps)

**EDIT**

The checkboxes names will need to be changed:

```
                    <input type="checkbox" name="newstype1" value="1"/>1<br/>
                    <input type="checkbox" name="newstype2" value="2"/>2<br/>
                    <input type="checkbox" name="newstype3" value="3"/>3<br/>
                    <input type="checkbox" name="newstype4" value="4"/>4<br/>
                    <input type="checkbox" name="newstype5" value="5"/>5<br/>
```

Comment: This will not work. All checkboxes have the **same** name. PHP will simply group theses into an array which can then be accessed the same way you've posted above, but without the repetitive `if`s

Comment: Can you not change the name of the checkboxes. (as done). Or will that still not work?

Comment: Yes changing the names like you have above will work with your PHP snippet. But you'll still end up with many `if` statements which isn't the best solution. If OP only has (5) news type, then yea that would still work too.

Answer (score 0):

You do not specify what environment you're working in. Environments such as Node.js, PHP, Python, Ruby, Java, etc.

So not knowing the above, you have two options:

1. Handle the form data when it's submitted. You'd look for all `newstype` params in the submitted form data.
2. Add some sort of listener to the form when submit is clicked that finds all checked boxes.

---

Using vanilla JS:

```
const checkboxes = document.querySelectorAll('input[name=newstype]:checked')
```